# A better Functional solutions to this Java Kata

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn more about functional programing. I did some training vids, and I thought I would do a Kata.

Maybe I just picked a bad one, I tried to make predicates to do the filter but it seemed to add more code than seemed needed. I'm sure there is a better way.

Thank you!

KATA -------

```
n:         2
oldValue: 'a'
newValue: 'o'
"Vader said: No, I am your father!" -> "Vader soid: No, I am your fother!"
  1     2          3        4       -> 2nd and 4th occurence are replaced
```

---

```
    package kata;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
    import java.util.function.BiPredicate;
    
    public class ReplaceEveryNth {
        public static Integer interPos = 0;
        
        //works but isn't great. How do you make this functional?

        public static String replaceNth(String text, Integer n, Character oldValue, Character newValue){
            //String builder allows for the setCharAt Function to swap char
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    
            //make an array of all the positions the char is found at.
            ArrayList<Integer> foundAt = new ArrayList<>();
            sb.toString().chars().forEach( c -> {
                interPos++;
                if (c == oldValue) foundAt.add(interPos);
            });
    
            //need to for mod div
            AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
            index.set(1);
    
            //if mod this pos is 0, then swap it.
            foundAt.forEach(pos -> {
                System.out.println("pos Mods: " + pos + " " + index);
                if (index.get() % n == 0) {
                    sb.setCharAt(pos-1, newValue);
                }
                index.getAndIncrement();
            });
    
            return sb.toString();
        }
    
    }
```

Edit this this updated method, it's not really functional? But it uses a single loop.

```
    public static String replaceNth(String text, Integer n, Character oldValue, Character newValue){
        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        char[] ret = new char[chars.length];
        int counter = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i)
        {
            ret[i] = chars[i];
            if (chars[i] == oldValue) {
                    if (counter % n == 0) {
                        ret[i] = newValue;
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return new String(ret);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you keep the indexes around? You could just replace them as found, and that way you'd only need the one stream.

Comment: No reason other......

Originally I made 2 predicates...

    static BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> shouldReplace = (pos, lastFound) -> {
        if ((lastFound + pos) == interPos) {
            System.out.println("FOUND");
        }

        return true;
    };

    static BiPredicate<Character, Character> foundReplaceChar = (c, oldValue) -> c.equals(oldValue);

and tried to use one loop, but it didn't make anything easier to read or less complicated. 

However, I may have just been doing things badly.

Comment: I had hoped to try to make something like:
return Stream.doSomething(predicate).dosomethingelse(whatever);

Comment: You can't filter your chars stream with a predicate, because you need even the chars that don't equal to old value to end up in the resulting string. To replace chars, you can `.map()` every char with a unary op, that's some sort of a "function-based" solution.

Comment: The way you're approaching it isn't very functional. One sign is that you're using mutable data (StringBuilder).  One "more functional" approach would be to 1. split the string by oldValue ("a"), 2. create a sequence of separators ('a', 'o', 'a', 'o', etc.), and finally 3. then join the pieces together again alternating the split values with the sequence.  Each step above could be its own function (perhaps an already given one like String.split)

Comment: @ajz "*The way you're approaching it isn't very functional.*" quite right. It's imperative/procedural but with `.forEach()` thrown in.

Comment: I'm trying to get me head around functional coding,  i completely agree it's not functional,  I'm trying to figure out how to make it functional so i appreciate the help.       Can go into a little more detail.  Ajz?  I'm not quit following but I'll try to split it as you suggest

Comment: @ajz I edited the main doc with a new method that uses a single loop, it's very java 1.4ish. Not sure if that what you had pictured?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the regular expression approach may be used here but generally a parameterized pattern may be created to replace each N-th occurrence of `oldValue` with `newValue`:

`"(oldValue)([^oldValue]*(oldValue[^oldValue]*){occurrence - 2})(oldValueToReplace)"`
Here 3 groups are used:

1. `(oldValue)` - the first occurrence
2. `([^oldValue]*(oldValue[^oldValue]*){occurrence - 2})` - zero or more entries of non-oldValue, followed by `oldValue` with a suffix which should appear `occurrence - 2` times
3. `(oldValueToReplace)` - the N-th occurrence to be replaced.

Also, the values outside character class `[]` should be escaped.

Example implementation:

```java
public static String replaceNth(String text, int n, char oldValue, char newValue) {
    String pattern = String.format("(%2$s)([^%1$s]*(%2$s[^%1$s]*){%3$d})(%2$s)", oldValue, Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(oldValue)), n - 2);
    
    return text.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2" + newValue);
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(replaceNth("Vader said: No, I am your father!", 2, 'a', 'o'));

System.out.println(replaceNth("... .... ..... .... ... ", 3, '.', 'x'));

System.out.println(replaceNth("xxxx abcd x dbca xxxx", 5, 'x', 'O'));

System.out.println(replaceNth("+---------------------", 7, '-', '+'));
```

Output:

```
Vader soid: No, I am your fother!
..x ..x. .x..x ..x. .x. 
xxxx abcd O dbca xxxx
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this, it's a great answer and in the workplace how I would dealt with it.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, I've put together something that I think is more functional (I'm no functional programming expert and my Java is a bit rusty).  I think that I went too far with "having fun" rather than more directly answering your question, so I'm sorry about that.

From what I've read one of the keys to functional programming is identifying "pure functions" (ones that have no side effects) and building on those.  Almost all useful code will have impure functions too, but by moving as much logic as possible into pure functions helps concentrate the impure stuff in hopefully well contained areas.

What I did is I broke the problem down into a few different general purpose functions and used those to solve the problem at hand.  I didn't get to this solution right away.  I started breaking things down and as I worked I tweaked the functions to be more and more general purpose.  It took me several iterations to get to what you see below.  The early iterations were kind of ugly but as I worked through things I was pleasantly surprised that I was able to get it to the point where it is now.

Thank you for asking this question.  I learned a lot trying to answer it.  I hope that in turn I was able to help you out too.

```
// Splits a string by the given character into a list of sub-strings
public static List<String> splitBy(String text, Character splitValue) {
    return Arrays.stream(text.split(Pattern.quote(splitValue.toString()), -1)).toList();
}

// Generates an infinite sequence where every Nth item is one value
// and all other values are another
// generateEveryNthSequence(3, 'A', 'B') =? ['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', ...]
public static <T> Stream<T> generateEveryNthSequence(int n, T everyNthValue, T everyOtherValue) {
    return Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).map(i -> i % n == 0 ? everyNthValue : everyOtherValue);
}

// Combines two sequences by alternating the values
// ['A','B','C'] and ['1','2','3'] => ['A', '1', 'B, '2', 'C', '3']
public static <T> Stream<T> alternateValues(Stream<T> stream1, Stream<T> stream2) {
    Iterator<T> iterator1 = stream1.iterator();
    Iterator<T> iterator2 = stream2.iterator();
    return Stream.iterate(iterator1, t -> t == iterator1 ? iterator2 : iterator1)
            .takeWhile(t -> t.hasNext())
            .map(t -> t.next());
}

public static String replaceNth(String text, Integer n, Character oldValue, Character newValue){
    // "V", "der s", "id: No, I ", "m your f", "ther!"
    List<String> segments = splitBy(text, oldValue);
    // "a", "o", "a", "o", ...
    Stream<String> separators = generateEveryNthSequence(n, newValue.toString(), oldValue.toString());
    // "V", "a", "der s", "o", "id: No, I ", "a", "m your f", "o", "ther!", "a"
    Stream<String> alternatingItems = alternateValues(segments.stream(), separators);
    // "V", "a", "der s", "o", "id: No, I ", "a", "m your f", "o", "ther!"
    Stream<String> alternatingItemsTrimmed = alternatingItems.limit(segments.size() * 2 - 1);
    // "Vader soid: No, I am your fother!"
    return alternatingItemsTrimmed.collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going over this, I wish I could have seen your process. I understand the concepts it's training to nail them down in practice is my goal.

I'm going to de-engineer this and study it. I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: public static <T> Stream<T> generateEveryNthSequence(int n, T everyNthValue, T everyOtherValue)

The one part that throws me is this. 
1. I didn't know how to get access to the index in a steam, that was great to learn!
Why I did a for loop when trying to follow your advice.

2. Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1). makes a new empty stream with an index of 1, for each step add 1. Go until....?

It works, but I get board waiting if I write it to the screen.  Is it going until 2,147,483,647?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present an alternative solution

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Vader said: No, I am your father!";
    String result = replacenth(input, 'a', 'o', 2);
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Vader soid: No, I am your fother!"));
}

private static String replacenth(String input, char search, char replace, int n) {
    return IntStream.range(1, input.length() + 1)
            .mapToObj(i -> input.substring(0, i))
            .map(s -> shouldReplace(s, search, n)
                    ? replace : s.charAt(s.length() - 1))
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    StringBuilder::new,
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::toString));
}

private static boolean isEqual(String s, char c) {
    return s.charAt(s.length() -1) == c;
}
private static Long countOccurences(String s, char c){ 
    return s.chars().filter(x -> x == c).count();
}
private static boolean shouldReplace(String s, char search, int n) {
    return isEqual(s, search) && countOccurences(s, search) % n == 0;
}
```

}